# Create and fill new array with data, if the current array extend its size of certain columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, extend

in advance:
i apologize for this may stupid and easy question.
heres my problem:
im currently working with huge data packages and have to extract specific values into an array. The code (which i havent written) is working, but it happens, that matlab slows down really hard, when the array is reaching a certain size.
My first idea is to segment the output into various arrays. I hope with that i can avoid any slow down. Also an save of the array and kick out of the workspace is possible for me.

But i struggle when it comes to tell the script to switch the array, which has to fill.
here my code i come so far:

```
 if counter ~= 18982 && rem(counter,18983) ~= 0
 array(counter,:) = [x y z x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9];

 elseif counter == 18983 || rem(counter,18983) == 0
 i=i+1
 name_str = ['array',int2str(i),'= 1'];
 eval(name_str)
```

my elseif will create a new array named as it should. But i have no idea how to adress it and manipulate. Im also worried about bringing this new array as a variable into code line two, because the first "if iteration" should work again.
May you can give me some suggestions how to solve this problem.
**Im happy about any suggestions or help, also if a total different approach than mine is the right one.**

Info to computer properties: this script will run on a cluster node, so 128 cores and 500GB Ram are available.

Thanks alot! :)

Comment: Can I ask for a clarification? You are getting 12 (ish) pieces of data for each iteration of some source. You are storing that data into an (n-by-12) array. And you want to keep the program from hanging when N gets too large? About what size of N are you talking about, for the whole data set?

Comment: hi Pursuit :)

were are talkin about data sizes, which approx. will generate N = 10^8 or higher. 
In a long term, this cant be sufficient to postprocess all these data without filtering at the beginning...

Comment: Using `eval` will slow your code down, not speed it up, because the [JIT compiler](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-execution-engine.html) can't work efficiently around the dynamic variable creation. This is one of several reasons why you should [avoid `eval`](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/). Please [edit] your question to turn your existing code into a [mcve] so we can reproduce the issue, for instance we can't tell from this whether you are pre-allocating `array` which would be essential for speed.

Comment: Hi Wolfie,
i read several times to avoid the eval function, but couldnt invent any other solution by myself to generate new arrays. may to mention that im a total beginner in coding, especially in matlab.
Im not sure how to build up a minimal reporducible example, cause my data are huge and confidential... closest assumption is an array "37000x12" and my code will read the array line by line to. for each line the values are set to the parameters [x y z ....]
My struggle is the Output. It should be 3 new arrays with max (18983 x 12).
Does this clarified my issue/struggle a bit to you?

Comment: but ill try to setup a minimal reproducible example, just give me few hours

Comment: You can just make a random array, we don't need your confidential data, but as I say whether or not you pre-allocate that output array will matter a lot, so if this is your complete code as-implemented then you are missing the pre-allocation, so your example should be a complete representation of what you're currently trying to do. Allocating 3 arrays will use no less memory than allocating to 1, so it's unclear why you're trying to do this, it would be good to state the actual aim (speed for large inputs?) if it doesn't actually depend on making new matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely an particularly awful incident of not pre-allocating your arrays.

A good maxim in Matlab: **when filling large arrays, always pre-allocate** (well, as much as possible)

As a motivational example, consider the following examples:

First, this code block seems to be about what you are doing. (I cut it off at 1e5 because I'm not very patient). The `x` variable is growing at each iteration. Under the hood, Matlab is copying data all the data into new memory location at each iteration.

```
clear x
tic
for ix = 1:1e5
    x(ix,[1:12]) = (1:12)*ix;
end
toc   %12.9 seconds
```

This is what happens after pre-allocating. Note that all I changed is to first set my output (`y` in this case) to a large array of zeros first, and then I fill it.

```
clear y
tic
y = zeros(1e5,12);
for ix = 1:1e5
    y(ix,[1:12]) = (1:12)*ix;
end
toc  %0.083 seconds
```

This difference probably grows with n^2, so by the time you get to 1e8 entries, you will be crawling.

Applying this to your code, try adding the following line before you start the loop: `array = zeros(n, 12)`, where `n` if your best guess of how large the array needs to be, rounded up.  (If you want to get fancier, you can look at methods to intelligently grow an array of unknown size. But that's a topic for another question.)

You probably (almost certainly) don't need to break your data up. I can fit a 1e8 x 12 array into memory just fine, and my computer is not as beefy as yours.

---

Follow-up:

Filling this out to a more realistic size, I get the following timing information at 1e8 lines

```
clear z
tic
z = zeros(1e8,12);
for ix = 1:1e8
    z(ix,[1:12]) = (1:12)*ix;
end
toc  %49 seconds
```

Comment: Hi Pursuit, thanks for pointing out the main problem, which i wasnt aware of. I didnt know, that matlab works as you described. I thought, matlab has the array always in RAM and checking about last row and extending, but not copying the whole array. Thanks for the explanation. Also, I basically implemented already your codelines, but didnt mentioned to raise my zeros as my default 1 x12. i thought its to generate a suitable array before filling, but the size doesnt matter. I tested the code again, and now its working properly.
Thanks alot to you and all the others! <3